# Php updating a span using javascript/ajax is not working properly

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax

I am updating a span using below script but it is working if condition is false and if condition is true it does not update.

What i observed that it executes the same false condition and when i click the second time it updates the quantity but less 1 number than the actual quantity of records in the database.

Like total records are 2 and when i click submit the script runs and if condition is true in the database records are updated = 3 but in the span it shows 2.

When i click 2nd time and in the database records are = 4 and in the span it shows 3.

**Button where i click and run the script**

```
<input onclick='updateTitems("1");' type="submit" class="btn-style-2 mg-left-5" value="ADD TO CART">
```

**script**

```
<script>
function updateTitems(id) {
    var uid = "<?php echo $ses_mem; ?>";
   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: 'inc/menu_update_total_items.php',
     data: "id=" + id + "&uid=" + uid,
     success: function(data) {
          $('.summary12').html(data);
     }
   });
}
</script>
```

**menu_update_total_items.php**

```
$user_id    =   $_GET['uid'];

$item   = "select count(*) as records 
from orders_temp
where user_id = '".$user_id."'
";
$itemq  = $dba->query($item);
$itemr  = $itemq->fetch_assoc();
$count  = $itemr['records'];
---------------------------------
$itemx  = "select count(*) as records 
from orders_temp
where date = now()
and user_id = '".$user_id."'
";
$itemqx     = $dba->query($itemx);
$itemrx     = $itemqx->fetch_assoc();

$check      = $itemrx['records'];

<span class="summary12"><!-- class of javascript -->
<?php
if ($check == 1){
    echo $count+1;
}else{
    echo $count;
}
?>
Items 
</span>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for that info i will take care. Can u please help in this case why it is not working properly???

Comment: What does that query return when run manually? Are you sure you're composing the correct query? Check `var_dump($itemrx)` as well.

Comment: @tadman it gives this `array(1) { ["records"]=> string(1) "0" } `

Comment: That's a zero count, so is that what you're expecting?

Comment: well im expecting 1 not 0

Comment: Next step is to check your data and find out why that's the case. Looks like no matching rows.

Comment: well im submitting the form with that button and also running this script and using `$itemrx` im checking if the record inserted and then using if condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying lot of things i came up with the following solution and the issue has been solved.

Please need your opinion on this. Thanks

**Button**

```
<input onclick='updateTitems();' type="submit" class="btn-style-2 mg-left-5" value="ADD TO CART">
```

**Script**

```
function updateTitems(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "menu_update_total_items.php",
      cache: false,
      success: function(data){
         $(".summary12").html(data);

    //div or span reload script after success
    setInterval(function () {
    $('.summary12').load('inc/menu_update_total_items.php');
    }, 1000);

      } 
    });
}
```

**menu_update_total_items.php**

```
<?php 
@session_start();
include ("inc/db.php");

$ses_mem =  session_id();

$items  = "select count(*) as trecords 
from orders_temp
where user_id = '".$ses_mem."' ";
$item   = $dba->query($items);
$count  = $toitemszx->fetch_assoc();
?>
<a href="cart/review" class="cart-link">
<i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i>
    <?php echo $count['trecords']; ?>
Items 
</a>
```